# How to add a new row with one value and all other NA values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a vector of sample IDs that are required to be in my dataframe (otherwise the function I am applying to them doesn't work) but are missing (called `missing`).

For each of the elements in `missing`, I want to add a row to the end of my dataframe where I include the ID but the rest of the data (for all the other columns) in the row is all NAs.

What I am currently trying, based on some other Stack Overflow posts I saw that talk only about adding empty rows, is as follows:

```
for (element in missing) {
    df[nrow(df)+1,] <- NA
    df[nrow(df),1] <- element
}
```

Is there a simpler and faster way to do this, since it takes some time for even 1000 missing elements, whereas I might later have to deal with a lot more.

Comment: It would be better to do a `merge()` and let that function create the missing NA values. Adding one row at a time is very inefficient. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Jub, do either of the answers resolve your question?

Answer (score 5):

**1)** Using the built-in `anscombe` data frame, this inserts two rows putting -1 and -3 in the x1 column.

```
library(tibble)
new <- c(-1, -3)
add_row(anscombe, x1 = new)
```

giving:

```
   x1 x2 x3 x4    y1   y2    y3    y4
1  10 10 10  8  8.04 9.14  7.46  6.58
2   8  8  8  8  6.95 8.14  6.77  5.76
3  13 13 13  8  7.58 8.74 12.74  7.71
4   9  9  9  8  8.81 8.77  7.11  8.84
5  11 11 11  8  8.33 9.26  7.81  8.47
6  14 14 14  8  9.96 8.10  8.84  7.04
7   6  6  6  8  7.24 6.13  6.08  5.25
8   4  4  4 19  4.26 3.10  5.39 12.50
9  12 12 12  8 10.84 9.13  8.15  5.56
10  7  7  7  8  4.82 7.26  6.42  7.91
11  5  5  5  8  5.68 4.74  5.73  6.89
12 -1 NA NA NA    NA   NA    NA    NA
13 -3 NA NA NA    NA   NA    NA    NA
```

**2)** Here is a base solution. `new` is from (1)

(If overwriting `anscombe` is ok, but typically this would make it harder to debug, then omit the first line and replace `anscombe2` with `anscombe`.)

```
anscombe2 <- anscombe
anscombe2[nrow(anscombe2) + seq_along(new), "x1"] <- new
```

**3)** Using the tibble package (or dplyr which imports this) we can use rows_insert.  `new` is from (1).

```
library(dplyr)
rows_insert(anscombe, tibble(x1 = new))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample data:

```r
samp <- data.frame(id = 1:10, val1 = 11:20, val2 = 21:30)
missing <- c(11, 13, 15)
```

1. *Merge*:

   ```r
   merge(samp, data.frame(id = missing), by = "id", all = TRUE)
   #    id val1 val2
   # 1   1   11   21
   # 2   2   12   22
   # 3   3   13   23
   # 4   4   14   24
   # 5   5   15   25
   # 6   6   16   26
   # 7   7   17   27
   # 8   8   18   28
   # 9   9   19   29
   # 10 10   20   30
   # 11 11   NA   NA
   # 12 13   NA   NA
   # 13 15   NA   NA
   ```
2. *Row-bind* with an external package:

   ```r
   data.table::rbindlist(list(samp, data.frame(id = missing)), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
   dplyr::bind_rows(samp, data.frame(id = missing))
   ```
3. *Row-bind* with base R, a little more work:

   ```r
   samp0 <- samp[rep(1, length(missing)),,drop = FALSE][NA,]
   samp0$id <- missing
   rownames(samp0) <- NULL
   rbind(samp, samp0)
   ```